# Cannot print black ink with any printer

Tags: windows-8.1

I cannot print black but colors print fine.  I have switched printers and black still will not print.  I use Windows 8.1.  Is there a problem with 8.1?  Can anyone help?

Comment: Printer model? Driver up to date? Cartridge calibrated? USB, LPT or WiFi?
 Too many variables... please explain what you've tried so far.

Comment: Also, when you say you've switched printers, do you mean different physical printers and none of them print black, or different printer selections that use the same physical printer, or different drivers?  What type of printers?  If multiple physical printers, do they share a commonality, like all have old black inkjet cartridges or potentially empty toner cartridges?

Comment: Driver needed to be updated.  Completed and problem resolved.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

This is the OP's comment that should be an answer:

> Driver needed to be updated. Completed and problem resolved.